# Pytest - How can I pass in a file from the command line for preliminary setup without setting up a test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a testscript setup in pycharm and I want to import a file to do some preliminary work. While this code works in python I'm getting errors in pytest.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', nargs='+', help='properties file')
args_namespace = parser.parse_args()
args = vars(args_namespace)['file']

thisdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.join(thisdir, args[0]))
```

However, when I run this with pytest, the error is:

ERROR: not found: /path/to/file/properties
(no name '/path/to/file/properties.ini' in any of [])

I believe what's happening is that pytest is trying to interpret this as it's own command rather than as something I'm passing in. Is there I way I can bring in the file without having to setup a specific pytest method and using the regular python argsparse library?